# Spring Boot Soap Integration Test Failing

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, soap, junit

I have a spring boot project with two apps, one in src/test and one in src/main. I have two apps, one mediator to connect with a SOAP endpoint and one acting as a mock server for testing my unit test and integration tests.

I want to create an integration test in my spring boot app to test a SOAPUI call for getVersion. I want to imitate a SOAPUI call in spring boot and test if it hits and I have to launch two apps this way (my mockserver to run the integration test and my main app to connect to the SOAP webservice)

Some things that I have is the URI I have to hit:

```
https://127.0.0.1:28433/dave/ws/billingtool
```

This is on the left side of my SOAPUI getVersion (the envelope request input)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.billing.nulogix.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getVersion/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have a WSDL defined in my main/resources along with a request StudyDetailsSchema.xjb and .xsd and a response.xsd

So far I have this as a test

```
@Autowired
    private String studyDetailDemo;
    @Test
    public void soapTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = Request.Post("https://127.0.0.1:28433")
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(studyDetailDemo, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

    }
```

This test fails though but I am not sure why. I have it configured to launch my src/test/app on port 9119 and my src/main/app on port 28433. In the pre-integration it starts my main App and then the test runs with my MockServerApp. They both close with the mockServerApp closing first and then the App closing post integration.

Here is my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nulogix</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing_mediator</artifactId>
    <version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>billing</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.14.0</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
        <jaxb2-specVersion>2.2</jaxb2-specVersion>
        <git-commit-id-plugin.version>2.2.4</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
        <nulogix-release-number>0.9.6_M2</nulogix-release-number>
        <git.version.number>${git.commit.time}.${git.commit.id.describe-short}</git.version.number>
        <nulogix-billing-response-schema>nulogixBillingResponse_1.1.xsd</nulogix-billing-response-schema>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformats-text</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id1-generate-service-end-point-from-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/billing_endpoint</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.service</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id2-generate-pojo-from-request-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/request_model</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.request</generatePackage>                            
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id3-generate-pojo-from-response-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/response</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>${nulogix-billing-response-schema}</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/response_model</generateDirectory>                           
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.response</generatePackage>                   
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</dateFormat><!--  human-readable part of the version id -->
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile><!-- somehow necessary. otherwise the variables are not available in the pom -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</Implementation-Version>
                        <Git-Version-Number>${git.version.number}</Git-Version-Number>
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                  </configuration>
            </plugin>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass> 
        </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When I run mvn verify to run just the integration test it says it opens port on 28433 and 9119

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) @ billing_mediator ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-19 23:43:10.175  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Starting App on Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 50954 (/Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/classes started by asluborski in /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator)
2019-08-19 23:43:10.177 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
2019-08-19 23:43:10.179  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-19 23:43:10.807  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e6919d9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-19 23:43:10.809  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47c57f47] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-19 23:43:10.837  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.183  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 28443 (https)
2019-08-19 23:43:11.202  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.202  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-08-19 23:43:11.211  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/asluborski/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.279  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-19 23:43:11.280  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1072 ms
2019-08-19 23:43:11.306  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/nulogix/ws/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.307  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.310  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.310  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.310  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.310  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:11.339 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
2019-08-19 23:43:11.339 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.port=9119
2019-08-19 23:43:11.339 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : Using http://127.0.0.1:9119
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/Users/asluborski/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-08-19 23:43:11.638 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-19 23:43:11.638 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.version=0.97
2019-08-19 23:43:11.638 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.name=Nulogix_Patient_Responsibility
2019-08-19 23:43:11.640 DEBUG 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.GetVersionEndPoint     : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-19 23:43:11.778  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-19 23:43:12.301  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 28443 (https) with context path ''
2019-08-19 23:43:12.304  INFO 50954 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Started App in 2.474 seconds (JVM running for 10.674)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) @ billing_mediator ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------



  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-19 23:43:18.744  INFO 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT      : Starting BillingMediatorIT on Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 50977 (started by asluborski in /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator)
2019-08-19 23:43:18.745 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT      : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
2019-08-19 23:43:18.747  INFO 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-19 23:43:19.410  INFO 50977 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4eacc45] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-19 23:43:19.443  INFO 50977 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-08-19 23:43:19.803  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9119 (http)
2019-08-19 23:43:19.820  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-19 23:43:19.821  INFO 50977 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-08-19 23:43:19.829  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/asluborski/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-08-19 23:43:19.914  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-19 23:43:19.914  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1141 ms
2019-08-19 23:43:19.999  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.000  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/services/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.006  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.007  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.007  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.007  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.007  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationRequestSizeLimitFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-19 23:43:20.021 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] .n.b.m.ApplicationRequestSizeLimitFilter : Filter 'applicationRequestSizeLimitFilter' configured for use
2019-08-19 23:43:20.073 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.GetVersionEndPoint     : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
SUREFIRE-859: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/Users/asluborski/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-08-19 23:43:20.430 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
2019-08-19 23:43:20.430 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.port=9119
2019-08-19 23:43:20.430 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : Using http://127.0.0.1:9119
2019-08-19 23:43:20.431 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-19 23:43:20.431 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.version=0.97
2019-08-19 23:43:20.431 DEBUG 50977 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.name=Nulogix_Patient_Responsibility
2019-08-19 23:43:20.657  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-19 23:43:21.125  INFO 50977 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9119 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-19 23:43:21.130  INFO 50977 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT      : Started BillingMediatorIT in 7.641 seconds (JVM running for 8.125)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.912 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT
soapTest(com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT)  Time elapsed: 0.239 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:28433 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.execute(Request.java:177)
    at com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.BillingMediatorIT.soapTest(BillingMediatorIT.java:30)

2019-08-19 23:43:21.377  INFO 50977 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Results :

Tests in error: 
  BillingMediatorIT.soapTest:30 » HttpHostConnect Connect to 127.0.0.1:28433 [/1...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:stop (post-integration-test) @ billing_mediator ---
[INFO] Stopping application...
2019-08-19 23:43:21.498  INFO 50954 --- [           main] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2019-08-19 23:43:21.501  INFO 50954 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) @ billing_mediator ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/failsafe-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.197 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-19T23:43:21-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) on project billing_mediator: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Is there something wrong with my POM setup?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to connect to port 28433? As you correctly stated, your local tomcat started on port 9119, which is usually the one you want to connect to, when you want to test an application running locally.

Comment: I will need it for my soap integration tests because it is a mediator and so I need to hit it.